# New YouTube playlist id not playing with google API's

Tags: api, youtube, playlist

I'm using the old Google Youtube player API version 1 to show a playlist of video's. This works fine for playlists created until recently. But new playlists have 32 characters and do not show up.

There is a new API with a demo page. Filling out the new playlist ID will not work with the demo neither. Any ID as how to get the new playlists working?

For the demo: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo
Set CONTENT on Load a playlist and try this one: PLEQVEDqp75YwI2YH4ckRjyhC-bxjkCaoY

See the working playlist: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEQVEDqp75YwI2YH4ckRjyhC-bxjkCaoY&feature=g-list

UPDATE

It seems to be a character problem. This example is working: PLEQVEDqp75YzkYdEN8KUaN1AECJb5LQwJ

Something to do with '-' characters? I tried using Urlencode() without luck.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?